# Finding the relative proportion for each element of an array against another array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have two arrays: A and B.

```py
A = np.array([65, 20, 140, 15, 75, 15])
B = np.array([15, 45, 75, 106, 135, 165])
```

A can be thought of as user input with shape (n,1) where n is arbitrary positive integer. 
B can be thought of as fixed spec with shape (m,1) where m is fixed and known.

I'm trying to get the relative proportion of each element of array A with respect to array B. The result would be a matrix M of shape (n, m) as follows:

```py
M

array([[0.  , 0.33, 0.67, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.83, 0.17, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.83, 0.17],
       [1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.67, 0.33, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]])
```

In the first row of M, second and third element are 0.33 and 0.67 because 65 (first element of A) is 33%/ 67% split between 45 and 75 (second and third) element of B.

```py
M[0,1] = (75 - 65) / (75-45)
M[0,2] = 1 - M[0,1]
```

I've been looking around but there seems to be no core function to do this.

Many thanks,

Comment: So `M[i,j] = (A[i]-B[j+1])/(B[j]-B[j+1])`?

Comment: No, as you can see in the fourth row of M, the first element is 1 because the fourth element of A equals the first element of B. Plus that would cause index out of bounds for B in the last cases?

Comment: But I do not really understand then how you obtain `(65-45)/(75-45)`? Wouldn't it make more sense to use `(65-45)/45`?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it should've been ```(75 - 65)/(75-45) ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be optimized, but it seems to be working:

```
def f(ar: np.ndarray, br: np.ndarray):
    m = np.zeros((ar.shape[0], br.shape[0]))
    for ar_el, m_row in zip(ar, m):
        left = br[br <= ar_el]
        right = br[br >= ar_el]
        left_e = left[-1]
        right_e = right[0]
        if left_e == right_e:
            m_row[len(left) - 1] = 1
        elif left_e == br[-1]:
            m_row[-1] = 1
        elif right_e == br[0]:
            m_row[0] = 1
        else:
            m_row[len(left) - 1] = (right_e - ar_el) / (right_e - left_e)
            m_row[len(left)] = (ar_el - left_e) / (right_e - left_e)
    return m
```

And the result for your data:

```
>>> np.around(f(a, b), decimals=2)
array([[0.  , 0.33, 0.67, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
   [0.83, 0.17, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
   [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.83, 0.17],
   [1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
   [0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
   [1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `B` is sorted and `min(B)<=min(A)` and `max(A)<max(B)`:

```
idx = B.searchsorted(A,'right')
d = np.diff((B[idx],A,B[idx-1]),axis=0)
out = np.zeros((A.size,B.size))
np.put_along_axis(out,np.add.outer(idx,(-1,0)),(d/d.sum(axis=0)).T,axis=1)

np.round(out,3)
# array([[0.   , 0.333, 0.667, 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
#        [0.833, 0.167, 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
#        [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.833, 0.167],
#        [1.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
#        [0.   , 0.   , 1.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
#        [1.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ]])
```